# Android MapFragment in ViewPager not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

my English is bad. I want use MapFragment in ViewPager, but my code is no working. Please, help me.

My app use white background color and when MapFragment started, background color becomes gray, and all.

My fragment_map.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

My MapFragment.java

```
package com.lomovskiy.android.testapp.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.lomovskiy.android.testapp.R;
import com.lomovskiy.android.testapp.activities.MainActivity;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private MapView mMapView = null;

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;

public static MapFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(MapFragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker")
            .draggable(true)
    );
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.TweetActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="is not null, i deleted this" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="is not null, i deleted this" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onCreateView()` method should have the view inflation code just like it does now, but you should move the map related code to `onViewCreated()` which is run when the Fragment is actually fully constructed.

Probably with your current code the `mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view)` might actually return null.

So you could try something like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
  return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
  mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```